# variation problem of smote for regression

Tags: python, regression, smote

I'm working on the estimation of ticket sales with insufficient and imbalanced data. To fix the problem, I'm using smoter(smote for regression) from smogn package, but each time I run my model, I've got different predictions on my target. I reckon that smoter would generate different output data each time. Is there any way to fix this random state?

Here is my code:

```
import smogn

def solution(df, p_bar: bool = 1, params: dict = model_params):
    # sort
    try:
        df = df.sort_values(["transition_date", "event_date"], ascending=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print("e")

    # bootstraping hyperparams
    n_samples = 140
    n_range = 40

    # tqdm
    if p_bar == 1:
        rg = tqdm(range(len(df)))
    else:
        rg = range(len(df))

    pred_list = []
    time.sleep(0.5)
    try:
        for i in rg:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            test_tour_id = df.iloc[i]['tour_id']
            df_without_test_tour = df[df['tour_id'] != test_tour_id].reset_index(drop=True)
            dt = smogn.smoter(
                data=df_without_test_tour,
                y='total_sales',
                k=3,
                samp_method='extreme',

                rel_thres=0.8,
                rel_method='auto',
                rel_xtrm_type='high',
                rel_coef=2.25
            )

            test_data = df.iloc[[i]].drop(e_col, axis=1)
            test_label = [df.iloc[i]['total_sales']]
            test_prid_id = df.iloc[i ]['promotion_id']

            train_data = dt.drop(e_col, axis=1)
            train_label = dt['total_sales']
            pred_tmp = []
            for j in range(n_range):
                x_train = resample(train_data, n_samples=n_samples, random_state=j)
                y_train = resample(train_label, n_samples=n_samples, random_state=j)

                model = xgb.get_model(x_train, y_train, params)
                pred = model.predict(test_data)

                pred_tmp.append(pred)

            pred = np.mean(pred_tmp, axis=0)
            mape_pred = abs(test_label - pred) * 100 / pred
            mape_real = abs(test_label - pred) * 100 / test_label

            pred_list.append([test_prid_id, pred[0], mape_pred[0], mape_real[0]])
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        tqdm._instances.clear() if p_bar == 1 else None

    pred = pd.DataFrame(pred_list, columns=['promotion_id', 'pred', 'mape_pred', 'mape_real'])
    return pd.merge(pred, df[e_col], how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `Smote Regress` have some randomness in the way it chooses the nearest neighbors:

Check out the line of code here in their code: [here](https://github.com/paobranco/SMOGN-LIDTA17/blob/8964a2327de19f6ca9e6f7055479ca863cd6b8a0/R_Code/DIBSRegress.R#L273)

Although I assume you are using the python version of it from [Nick Kunz's Repository](https://github.com/nickkunz/smogn), I advise you use the R one from [here](https://github.com/paobranco/SMOGN-LIDTA17). If you are using Python for your machine learning project, consider using `rpy2` python module in order to communicate between R and Python